# Convert a function into a lambda

Tags: python, function, class, lambda, getch

This code checks if the system is Windows or Linux, imports the needed libs, and defs a working "getch" function.
But... Can the function "_d" be done inside a lambda?

```
def _d():
    import sys, tty, termios
    f = sys.stdin.fileno()
    o = termios.tcgetattr(f)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        c = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(f, termios.TCSADRAIN, o)
    return c

_u = type('', (), {
    '__init__': lambda s: setattr(s, '', (None for sys in [__import__('sys')] for tty in [__import__('tty')])),
    '__call__': _d()
})

_w = None if ImportError else __import__("msvcrt").getch()

getch = (type('', (), {
    '__init__': lambda s: setattr(s, 'i', _u()) if ImportError else setattr(s, 'i', _w()),
    '__call__': lambda s: s.i()
}))()
```

I currently have:

```
setattr(type('',(),{}), '', (
    None for sys in [__import__('sys')]
    for tty in [__import__('tty')]
    for termios in [__import__('termios')]
    for f in sys.stdin.fileno()
    for o in termios.tcgetattr(f)
    for _ in tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
    for c in sys.stdin.read(1)
    for _ in termios.tcsetattr(f, termios.TCSADRAIN, o)
))
```

But that doesn't let me return "c".

Comment: Wow... Why on earth do you want to do that? Also, `lambda s: _d()` should just be `_d`.

Comment: Just because.
And thx, I missed that one after I changed the code in "_u.__call__".

Comment: This is a really, really bad idea. The peg doesn't fit into the hole, okay? Please stop trying to cram it in. You're going to break the damn thing.

Comment: No need to edit the answer into the question. Best to let the question be the question and the answers be the answers.

Comment: BTW you cannot catch exception using `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you must:

```
lambda: exec("""
def _d():
    import sys, tty, termios
    f = sys.stdin.fileno()
    o = termios.tcgetattr(f)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        c = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(f, termios.TCSADRAIN, o)
    return c
""", globals()) or _d()
```

It seemed more readable than the alternatives.

---

To fix your given code, though, try:

```
lambda: next(
    c
    for sys in [__import__('sys')]
    for tty in [__import__('tty')]
    for termios in [__import__('termios')]
    for f in [sys.stdin.fileno()]
    for o in [termios.tcgetattr(f)]
    for _ in [tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())]
    for c in [sys.stdin.read(1)]
    for _ in [termios.tcsetattr(f, termios.TCSADRAIN, o)]
)
```

Comment: @WilliamFernandes Well, then better use Perl. In Python **Readability counts.**

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I'm trying to get that whole code to fit in a single variable statement, to use it in my Python script.